# run Console cake on EC2/EB

Tags: cakephp, amazon-ec2, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to run Console/cake on EC2 (elastic beanstalk ) but It doesn't work
so first I run:

```
chmod +x Console/cake
```

then :

```
cd /path/to/cakephp/app && Console/cake
```

I got this error on the console :

```
No such file or directory
```

Comment: How can it be that you first run the chmod command and then cd to where the file is?

Comment: run chmod +x Console/cake on /path/to/cakephp/app

Answer (score 1):

Solved by installing dos2unix .
First you have to install dos2unix

```
sudo yum install dos2unix or sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

Then run:

```
sudo dos2unix /path/to/app/Console/cake
```

Maybe you need also to grant

```
chmod -R 777 app/Console
```